# How to redirect incoming traffic (HTTP, HTTPS) to specified server which is accessible behind SOCKS4 proxy?

Tags: iptables, proxy, transparent-proxy, socks

[servers setup schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDWdc.png)

I have a web application on a "Server behind proxy", which is not accessible through internet. It's only accessible through "SOCKS4 server", which I can't change anything on. I have a domain with IP address set to "Redsocks server" and I want users to access my web application on that domain. I've looked at redsocks docs and some questions about related issues but I couldn't find any that covered my problem.